# BASH - Renombrando archivos

Tags: bash, shell

Tengo que renombrar los archivos terminados en ".cpp" a ".cc". Para ello, pensé el siguiente código:

```
#!/bin/bash
route="."

if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
    route=$1
fi

for file in $(find $route -name *.cpp)
do
    newName=$(dirname $file)'/'$(basename $file .cpp).cc
    mv $file $newName
done
```

El problema es que los archivos no los renombra y los deja en la carpeta donde estaban, sino que los mueve al directorio desde donde ejecuto el script, ¿Alguna idea sobre el fallo?

Comment: Interesante aportación: [How to loop through file names returned by find?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9612090/1983854).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

intentarea ayudarte con un script....

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in *.cpp; do
    BASENAME="${FILE%%.cpp}"
    mv "${FILE}" "${BASENAME}.cc"
done
```

Esto sirvio para mi :D... cualquier duda comenta

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre una forma de hacerlo usando una línea de código, con el comando find y bash:

```
 find /inserte/path/absoluto -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec /bin/bash -c 'vkk="{}"; mv "$vkk" "${vkk:0:${#vkk}-4}.cc"' \;
```

**Nota:** Por tu shebang he asumido que existe /bin/bash. Modifica el /bin/bash de después del parámetro -exec a donde lo tengas si no lo tienes en /bin/bash.

Answer (score 0):

El comando mv se está ejecutando desde la ruta en la que se ejecuta el script. Si quieres que se renombre en la carpeta donde está el fichero .cpp tendrás que hacer un cd a esa ruta o ejecutar mv con rutas relativas.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta es super divertida y muy bonita. En mi trabajo teníamos que renombrar varios archivos "*.py" para un ambiente de pruebas y tratamos por todas las maneras a gusto de cada quien. Yo preferí tratar de usar shell scripting y utilicé la mayoría de lo recomendado en las respuestas, incluso utilicé varias veces xargs y varios command substitution, otro compañero se rindió e hizo un script en python pero al final la respuesta fue demasiado sencilla y bonita.

Utiliza `rename`.

En tu caso puedes usar esto:

```
$ rename 's/.cpp/.cc/' *
```

Creo que la sintaxis se explica por si sola, en caso contrario, rename recibe un patrón que indica la sustitución de lo que contenga .cpp por .cc en la expansión completa de archivos (por el glob) en la carpeta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es bonito porque el programa `rename` fue creado por Larry Wall, el creador de Perl, y divertido porque a todo mundo lo hace pensar de más para algo "sencillo".

Otra forma en la que lo puedes hacer, si te gusta algo un poco más complicado, es:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "*.cpp" | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo {} $(echo {} | sed "s/cpp/cc/g")' | xargs -I {} bash -c "mv {}"
```

El resultado es el mismo.